# why .bashrc not executed when open a new terminal?

Tags: linux

According to the bash startup description, `.bashrc` should be reloaded when doing a non-login interactive shell.

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.

I append a new variable into `.bashrc` like `NAME="TEST_BASHRC"` then save it.
But when open a new terminal, the variable `$NAME` is still None. That is to say, `.bashrc` isn't reloaded when opening new terminal.
Why `.bashrc` not executed and how can I make `.bashrc` reload when opening new terminal?

The following is what I do:

```
# comment: append variable "NAME" to .bashrc
$ cat .bashrc
export NAME="TEST_BASHRC"
# comment: open a new terminal then...
$ echo $NAME

$
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks for doing the research and determining that this is not specific to `CLASSPATH`, `PYTHON_PATH`, or whichever specific variable you were trying to configure. Your particular terminal emulator most likely starts a login shell. Login shells use `~/.bash_profile` instead. You can add `source ~/.bashrc` to `.bash_profile` to ensure all shells will use it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but about Linux usage. I suggest to re-ask this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score -1):

You need to export the variable:

Try:

```
export NAME="TEST_BASHRC"
```

See [why here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107851/using-export-in-bashrc)

Comment: tested on my Linux - edited my .bashrc and added `NAME="Hello world"` and exited, sourced bashrc and it worked .. - even opened new tab and it worked

Comment: Seems it not works that just updating to `export NAME="TEST_BASHRC"`. Whether I need do some other operation?I don't want to manually source the `.bashrc` because I want to test the `.bashrc` will be automatically executed when opening a new terminal.

Comment: Please avoid answering [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) fodder. Instead, close it and move on. It is sometimes helpful to suggest a site where the question may be on-topic.